# Quarkus extension for spring data API - automatic repository implementation generation

Tags: spring-data, cdi, quarkus, spring-repositories, hibernate-jpa

I am trying to migrate a spring project in quarkus and I am using quarkus extension for spring data API.

As they said in the quarkus doc : Interfaces that extend org.springframework.data.repository.Repository are automatically implemented and the generated repositories are also registered as beans so they can be injected into any other bean (source : https://quarkus.io/guides/spring-data-jpa#what-is supported). But in the spring doc they said that instead of extending org.springframework.data.repository.Repository we can alternatively annotate our interface with @RepositoryDefinition and it will cause the same behaviour as extending org.springframework.data.repository.Repository (source : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.definition-tuning).

My question is : Does spring data API generate automatically the repository that is annotated with @RepositoryDefinition since it has the same behavior as extending org.springframework.data.repository.Repository ?

If no, is there any other way to make spring data API generate the repository that is annotated with @RepositoryDefinition ?

Note that I can't modify the package where the interface is declared since it is a third party library.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to my own question.

I have opened an issue in github. And it turns out that @RepositoryDefinition isn't supported at the moment. But there is a good chance that it will be supported soon. You can follow the issue [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/10614).